# How does Q.all work in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, q

I have the following code:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var promises = [];
a.forEach(function(item,index){
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    doSomething().then(function(){
        deferred.resolve(true);
        promises.push(deferred);
    });
});

Q.all(promises).then(function(data){
    console.log("something!!");
});
```

How does Q.all know that promises array has all the promises required by forEach loop?
Sometimes, my Q.all runs before forEach. Please tell me where I am going wrong.

doSomething() is an asynchronous function which returns a promise.

Comment: Can you give some practical example? You are ignoring `item` and `index`. Even if you get answers I am not sure you can directly use them for your actual problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Q.all` cannot run before your `forEach`, since `forEach` is synchronous.

But you actually push things in the array *after* Q.all has been called. Your way of using promises is a bit awkward : no need to use a deffered in a promise!

Plus, you don't want to push the deffered itself but the promise that it holds, after rejecting or resolving it. See below for more info on how to "promisify" an asynchronous funtion.

Deffered are used to define promises out of symple callback-based asynchronous code. Since `doSomething()` returns a promise (you are using `.then()`), you could actually just do :

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var promises = [];
a.forEach(function(item,index){
    var promise = doSomething().then(function(data){
        return Q(true);
    });
    promises.push(promise);
});

Q.all(promises).then(function(data){
    console.log("something!!");
});
```

Then promises will be directly populated with promises, without any delay.

EDIT : since you are asking about `doSomething` not being promise-enabled, here is what you could do:

Let's say `doSomething` takes as a parameter a callback to execute after some asynchronous task.

Then you could wrap `doSomething` that way:

```
function doSomethingPromise(){
    var defered = Q.defer();
    doSomething(function(err,data){
       if(err){
           defered.reject(err);
       }
       else{
           defered.resolve(data);
       }
    });
    return defered.promise;
}
```

and then use `doSomethingPromise()` as mentionned above, instead of `doSomething`, since this one returns a promise.

Comment: Thanks! And what if I don't return promise in doSomething? i.e. doSomething is just an asynchronous function and I want to run Q.all after forEach is completed.

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain how to "promisify" a non-promise asynchronous function.

Comment: I think @skjindal93 has over-simplified his code here; the value of the item is not even used. I don't think this is the problem we should focus on though.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tiesselune.

Comment: Hi, it's a good starting point. I was wondering me, how catch errors in doSomething() inside forEach loop. It would be like this?: 

doSomething()
   .then(d => {return Q(true);})
   .catch(e => {return Q(e);});

Comment: @Tiesselune can this Q.all be nested multiple times?

Comment: Q.All returns a promise, that can be added to an array on which you call Q.all, and so on, so yes, it can. I'll just add that now that ES6 promises exist, Q is a little less relevant since you can do everything it does without using a library. But if your project uses Q, well, stick with it if you don't want to convert all your promises to standard ones

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when `Q.all` is executed, the `promises` array is still empty.  Deferred objects are being pushed onto `promises` asynchronously, so `Q.all()` will be executed before the promise from `doSomething()` is resolved.